# Why isn't my observeEvent function responding to the button id and creating the modal in my server for my R Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

Per the title, can someone help me figure out why the `observeEvent` isn't responding to the button press and rendering the modal?

#### UI

Here is the code to describe the UI.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shiny.semantic)

ui <- div(
  div(
  class = "ui fixed inverted menu " , style = " height:100px;background-color:black",
  div(class = "row", shiny.semantic::actionButton('hom',label = 'Home', style = " height:30px;width:100px;margin-top:30px;margin-left:800px;background-color:black;color:white;font-style: oblique;font-weight: bold" ),actionButton('abo','About',style = "height:30px;width:100px;background-color:black;color:white;font-family: Verdana;font-style: oblique;font-weight: bold") ,button('ski','Skills',style = "height:30px;width:100px;background-color:black;color:white;font-style: oblique;font-weight: bold"),button('exp','Experience',style = "height:30px;width:100px;background-color:black;color:white;font-style: oblique;font-weight: bold"),button('con','Contact',style = "height:30px;width:100px;background-color:black;color:white;font-style: oblique;font-weight: bold"),Position = "inline")))
```

#### Server

Here is the code that represents the server.

```r
server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$hom,{
    create_modal(modal(
      id = 'aboutsai',
      class = 'fullscreen overlay',
      header = list(h1('sai', style="color:red")),
      content = list(
        h1('about sai')
      ),
      
      footer = list(action_button('backabout','GO BACK'))
    ))
  })
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It seems like the question you've asked might be more easily answered if you could provide a minimally reproducible example. This would include you removing the extra parts of your code that aren't relevant to your question. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) are the guidelines on how to ask a good question. Another important question is: where does the `create_modal` function you're calling come from? Unless we have all relevant part s of your code, we won't be able to help.

Comment: I have edited the question  and create_modal is coming from shiny.semantic package

Comment: Ok. Since you're not calling it via `shiny.semantic::create_modal`, please edit your post to show all of the libraries you're importing, including `shiny.semantic`. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your `observeEvent` not responding to the button clicks is that your `ui` currently only is a `div`. However, using `shiny.semantic` you should wrap it inside a `semanticPage()` and it will work.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.semantic)

ui <- semanticPage(
    div(
        class = "ui fixed inverted menu " ,
        style = " height:100px;background-color:black",
        div(
            class = "row",
            shiny.semantic::actionButton('hom', label = 'Home', style = " height:30px;width:100px;margin-top:30px;margin-left:800px;background-color:black;color:white;font-style: oblique;font-weight: bold"),
            actionButton('abo', 'About', style = "height:30px;width:100px;background-color:black;color:white;font-family: Verdana;font-style: oblique;font-weight: bold") ,
            button('ski', 'Skills', style = "height:30px;width:100px;background-color:black;color:white;font-style: oblique;font-weight: bold"),
            button('exp', 'Experience', style = "height:30px;width:100px;background-color:black;color:white;font-style: oblique;font-weight: bold"),
            button('con', 'Contact', style = "height:30px;width:100px;background-color:black;color:white;font-style: oblique;font-weight: bold"),
            Position = "inline"
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$hom, {
        create_modal(
            modal(
                id = 'aboutsai',
                class = 'fullscreen overlay',
                header = list(h1('sai', style = "color:red")),
                content = list(h1('about sai')),
                
                footer = list(action_button('backabout', 'GO BACK'))
            )
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```