# Why my button is not responding even if i am giving it in the observevent and wants to create a modal when user click on the button

Tags: r, shiny

**Why my button is not responding even if i am giving it in the observevent and wants to create a modal when user click on the button ?**

**Note : Create_modal is a part of shinysemantic package
**

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.semantic)

ui <- div(
  div(
    class = "ui fixed inverted menu " , style = " height:100px;background-color:black",
    div(class = "row", shiny.semantic::actionButton('hom',label = 'Home', style = " height:30px;width:100px;margin-top:30px;margin-left:800px;background-color:black;color:white;font-style: oblique;font-weight: bold" ))))


server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$hom,{
    create_modal(modal(
      id = 'aboutsai',
      class = 'fullscreen overlay',
      header = list(h1('sai', style="color:red")),
      content = list(
        h1('about sai')
      ),
      
      footer = list(action_button('backabout','GO BACK'))
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't my observeEvent function responding to the button id and creating the modal in my server for my R Shiny app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76335662/why-isnt-my-observeevent-function-responding-to-the-button-id-and-creating-the)